# Ruby on rails .try() not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do the following:

```
    <%= order.user.try(:first_name) %>
    <%= order.user.try(:last_name) %>
    <%= order.user.try(:email) %>
```

This works however when I view the index of this page, the data does not appear in the table. I also viewed the logs and saw that the relevant data is being posted

> Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-18 11:15:02 +0000
>   Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"?",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"Rjf7+Z8UAPh9ZofIrOs+p6AoGPfgd/6rfdTRqJLtx0g=",
>   "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"TestHome",
>   "email"=>"test@test.com"}, "order"=>{"address"=>"3433234243",
>   "card_number"=>"45423554213994", "card_type"=>"visa",
>   "card_expires_on(1i)"=>"2013", "card_expires_on(2i)"=>"2",
>   "card_expires_on(3i)"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Confirm Order"}   Cart Load
>   (0.0ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1

so I alternatively tried to do

```
    <%= order.user.first_name %>
    <%= order.user.last_name %>
    <%= order.user.email %>
```

Doing this resulted in

```
NoMethodError in Orders#index

Showing C:/Users/sites/e-smart/app/views/orders/index.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I understand that the result of this error is because `first_name` is empty.

What is the best way to get the data.

**Order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :card_expires_on, :card_type, :ip_address, :card_number, :first_mame, :last_name, :email, :quantity
  belongs_to :cart 
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy   
  belongs_to :user
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :role_users
  has_many :orders
```

Comment: you can try <%= order.user && order.user.first_name %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying:

> I understand that the result of this error is because first_name is empty.

This is not correct. The cause of the error is that user is nil. This is also in line with the behavior or `try()` to return -blank-.

Make sure you have an order with the user populated correctly. This means your order table must have a user_id and the user must be assigned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two different things here - the `try` is working correctly in your view, it's returning nil when you call it on nil (`undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass` is because order.user is nil, not because `first_name` is nil.

This is unrelated to your POST - what is the actual issue you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify the meaning of this error first.

```
  NoMethodError in Orders#index

  Showing C:/Users/sites/e-smart/app/views/orders/index.html.erb where line #18 raised:

  undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

The above error doesn't mean that **first_name** for user is empty, but the user object itself is **nil**. It means that, your @order.user is **nil** and not **@order.user.first_name** is empty.

So, order.user.try(:first_name) should be read as **print the first_name of the user who placed this order if there is an user associated with the order, otherwise do nothing but don't throw any error**

The parameters in the form are being sent properly to your controller and may be you are missing something in the controller that associates the order and user records. Look into the controller action that is saving the object and make sure you are associating order and user properly.

Hope this helps